# Link for search help via meta site ignores keyword

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, per-site-meta

If you open the *contact* page via meta site, you can see a form with search box, e.g. in [3d printing meta](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/contact):

> [image: search]

Searching for example for "privilege" gives you some results with a link at the end:

> [image: link]

As you can see link contains `q` param with `privilege` as a value. But if you click [that link](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=privilege), param will be ignored. Result page will show an empty search box:

> [image: empty]

For main sites such link works as expected.

Comment: Yeah, IMO best solution is have the contact us page itself redirect to the main site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure that is the best, but probably is the easiest way to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect will be working correctly in the next build (rev 2017.2.14.25084).