# How to see badge list on child metas?

Tags: support, badges, per-site-meta

On the sites I visit I can see a list of all badges by: click on the question mark, visit help center, click on View a full list of badges you can earn. However if I go to the corresponding child meta and follow the same steps I see the list for the main site, not the child meta. Is this a bug, a feature or a user error?

In case you are wondering this is driven by curiosity about the last column shown which gives the number of times each badge has been awarded so if there is another way of accessing that then that would solve my particular issue. I do know that I can see which badges I have on my profile and also see the progress towards a proper subset of them by clicking on the little cogwheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because child metas don't have their own Help Center; they share it with the main site. **Once you click on the question mark, you're effectively on the main site.**

Alternatives are to just type `/help/badges/` behind the root URL of the meta site (e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/), or use the link in the achievements dialog:

[image]

Comment: Very neat and as a bonus using the achievement dialogue is more direct than the way I was doing it.

Comment: As far as I recall redirecting for help pages was set as a fix for my old [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291004/339911).